# Why does SVN sometimes "forget" that an entire folder has been added and deletes it on commit?

Tags: svn, version-control

Maybe someone can explain this behavior.  Sometimes I will do an SVN update, and for some reason SVN will forget that a file is under source control, and it will delete it from my directory; I have to `Revert` to add the files back.

Just now I made a change in a file and went to commit it.  The change was `Deleted` instead, which I quickly realized after pressing the Commit button.  Checking the folder, I found that **none** of the files under there were under version control anymore; SVN had somehow "forgotten" (without running an update at all before now) that they had been added to it at all, and had I committed the entire directory it would have deleted *everything*.  Again, I had to revert the folder, re-add the file I changed, and re-commit my change with a note that the previous commit incorrectly deleted the file.

Any idea why this happens?  I also frequently run into "Your tmp directory is corrupt.  Run cleanup" errors nearly every time I try to update my working copy; I basically have to run Cleanup *every time* before I run an Update.

I did not set up the SVN system here at work, and I have no idea how it's configured.  I have not encountered this kind of "flakiness" with SVN at any job previously that was using it.

EDIT:  I am using VisualSVN 1.7.11 and (occasionally) TortoiseSVN, on Windows XP.  Repository is hosted on Windows Server 2003 (Standard, I think).

Comment: What SVN client are you using?

Comment: VisualSVN/TortoiseSVN.  Edited OP to state this.

Comment: And what is serving the repository?

Comment: You mean the server?  It's Windows Server 2003, but I have no idea how SVN was set up or with what options.

Comment: What does the repository URL look like? Is it http(s) or file:///?

Comment: Completely random guess: One or more of your `.svn` folders got deleted accidentally?

Comment: It's `svn://dev.ourdomain.com/Projects`

Comment: @MatrixFrog: Could be, but why out of the blue?  Also I've had it happen from other people's checkins as well; this was just the first time it's happened to me.  The folder itself is still under version control (since I'm able to revert the entire thing), just all of the files in it were flagged for deletion.

Comment: @Wayne M: Alright, so that means its not file-based over a network share (we had weird things like that happen back when our repo's were just sitting on a windows network share, the repo would corrupt pretty easily). Have you tried doing a fresh checkout?

Comment: Not in a while I haven't.  I'll try that.  It strikes me as odd because I've used SVN for like two years and I've never run into these issues before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this happened also without doing an update/commit/... I'm pretty sure you have an app running that 'cleans' up empty files or empty folders, or otherwise messes with your files.

Subversion uses hidden .svn folders to hold its metadata. Some of the files in that folder are empty, and even some of the folders there are usually empty and only filled with files during some operations.

Now, if some other app is removing those empty files and folders, then svn can't work properly anymore and you can end up with a corrupt/broken working copy, and even get the wrong status.

Comment: I'll have to check.  It seems to be very sporadic that it happens; I'll go weeks with it working fine and then all of a sudden a random update/commit will mark everything in this one folder (only that folder) as "Deleted".